# Query to get comparison of fields in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to build a logic to get the matching fields in the report in a way that I should be able to compare reports side by side as shown in the "Expected Query Output" screenshot.

Rows in the existing table:-

[image]

Expected query output:-

[image]

To get this, I tried to build a `SQL Query` with `INNER JOIN`.
But seems this is not going to work in this scenario. Now my mind running blank.
Can someone guide me in proper direction ?

Below is the sample code I tried to build.

```
; WITH CTE AS (
          SELECT 'R1' AS ReportName, 'A' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R1' AS ReportName, 'B' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R1' AS ReportName, 'C' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R1' AS ReportName, 'D' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R2' AS ReportName, 'A' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R2' AS ReportName, 'B' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R2' AS ReportName, 'D' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R3' AS ReportName, 'K' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R3' AS ReportName, 'C' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R4' AS ReportName, 'P' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R4' AS ReportName, 'Q' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R4' AS ReportName, 'R' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R5' AS ReportName, 'A' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R5' AS ReportName, 'B' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
UNION ALL SELECT 'R5' AS ReportName, 'L' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
)

SELECT C1.ReportName, count(C1.FieldName), C2.ReportName, COUNT(C2.FieldName) FROM CTE C1
inner join CTE C2 
on C1.FieldName = C2.FieldType
and C1.FieldType = C2.FieldType
group by C1.ReportName, C2.ReportName
```

A logic without code is also welcome :)

Comment: You need to explain the relationship in the data that can generate your expected output. How's the relationship that makes 3 rows of R1 (and R2, R3, R4 in matchreport) but only one row of R2 (with R1 in match report) etc.

Comment: Single table has report names & fields it contains. & I want to compare the reports those are having common fields (measure & dimensions) as shown in the expected output. I want the total count as well so that I can get a detailed view. So we can say relationship is many to many ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
      ; WITH CTE AS (
                  SELECT 'R1' AS ReportName, 'A' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R1' AS ReportName, 'B' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R1' AS ReportName, 'C' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R1' AS ReportName, 'D' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R2' AS ReportName, 'A' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R2' AS ReportName, 'B' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R2' AS ReportName, 'D' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R3' AS ReportName, 'K' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R3' AS ReportName, 'C' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R4' AS ReportName, 'P' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R4' AS ReportName, 'Q' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R4' AS ReportName, 'R' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R5' AS ReportName, 'A' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R5' AS ReportName, 'B' FieldName, 'D' FieldType
        UNION ALL SELECT 'R5' AS ReportName, 'L' FieldName, 'M' FieldType
        )
SELECT DISTINCT A.REPO_NAME1, RC1,B.REPO_NAME2, RC2, MF  
FROM  (SELECT C1.ReportName AS REPO_NAME1, FieldName AS FIELD_N1, FieldType AS FIELD_T1,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C1.ReportName) AS RC1
        FROM CTE C1
        ) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT C2.ReportName AS REPO_NAME2,  FieldName AS FIELD_N2, FieldType AS FIELD_T2,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C2.ReportName) AS RC2
        FROM CTE C2
        ) B ON A.FIELD_N1 = B.FIELD_N2
        and A.FIELD_T1 = B.FIELD_T2
        AND A.REPO_NAME1 <> B.REPO_NAME2
LEFT JOIN (SELECT C3.ReportName AS REPO_NAME1, C4.ReportName AS REPO_NAME2, COUNT(*) AS MF
            FROM CTE C3
            LEFT JOIN CTE C4 ON C3.FieldName = C4.FieldName
                            AND C3.FieldType = C4.FieldType
                            AND C3.ReportName <> C4.ReportName
           GROUP BY C3.ReportName, C4.ReportName
           ) D ON A.REPO_NAME1 = D.REPO_NAME1 AND B.REPO_NAME2= D.REPO_NAME2
ORDER BY A.REPO_NAME1
```

Output:

```
  REPO_NAME1 RC1         REPO_NAME2 RC2         MF
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
R1         4           R2         3           3
R1         4           R3         2           1
R1         4           R5         3           2
R2         3           R1         4           3
R2         3           R5         3           2
R3         2           NULL       NULL        NULL
R3         2           R1         4           1
R4         3           NULL       NULL        NULL
R5         3           NULL       NULL        NULL
R5         3           R1         4           2
R5         3           R2         3           2
```

Comment: My SQL was missing with the MatchCount field. So I am not getting the match count as in the expected out put in above query as well ... :(

Comment: @Aditya: can you try new version (2) posted? Is it possibile your expected result is not fully coherent with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ReportName NVARCHAR(2),Field NVARCHAR(2), FieldType NVARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
('R1','A','M'),('R1','B','D'),('R1','C','D'),('R1','D','D'),('R2','A','M'),('R2','B','D'),('R2','D','D'),
('R3','K','M'),('R3','C','D'),('R4','P','D'),('R4','Q','D'),('R5','A','M'),('R5','B','D'),('R5','L','M')

;WITH AA AS (SELECT ReportName,Count(ReportName) TotalFields FROM @table GROUP BY ReportName)

SELECT AA.ReportName,AA.TotalFields,BB.MatchReport,CC.TotalFields FROM AA LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT A.ReportName,B.ReportName MatchReport FROM @table A 
LEFT JOIN @table B ON A.Field = B.Field AND A.FieldType = B.FieldType AND A.ReportName<>B.ReportName) BB ON AA.ReportName = BB.ReportName
LEFT JOIN AA CC ON BB.MatchReport = CC.ReportName
```